# Brownie ConnectionResetError on running forks

Tags: ganache, brownie, ganache-cli

I am running a test script with mainnet-fork using alchemy.

The test appears to be successfully completed, but during the tear down bit, brownie throws up:
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

**The full readout:**

```
PS D:\Remix Projects\Patrick Colins\Solidity with Python\Lesson7 - Lottery> brownie test --network mainnet-fork
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

====================================================================================================== test session starts ====================================================================================================== 
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: D:\Remix Projects\Patrick Colins\Solidity with Python\Lesson7 - Lottery
plugins: eth-brownie-1.18.1, hypothesis-6.27.3, forked-1.4.0, xdist-1.34.0, web3-5.27.0
collected 1 item

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --accounts 10 --fork https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/QQSu6nAAnOvWlkS9KTHk9UGk-kxieDmj --mnemonic brownie --port 8545 --hardfork istanbul'...

tests\test_lottery.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                    [100%]

====================================================================================================== 1 passed in 15.00s =======================================================================================================
Terminating local RPC client...
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen      
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1377, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 320, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 281, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1377, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 320, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 281, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\ganache.py", line 124, in _request
    response = web3.provider.make_request(method, args)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\providers\rpc.py", line 88, in make_request
    raw_response = make_post_request(
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\request.py", line 48, in make_post_request
    response = session.post(endpoint_uri, data=data, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 577, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\state.py", line 332, in _add_to_undo_buffer
    self.sleep(0)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\state.py", line 375, in sleep
    self._time_offset = int(rpc.Rpc().sleep(seconds))
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\__init__.py", line 45, in wrapped
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\__init__.py", line 166, in sleep
    return self.backend.sleep(seconds)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\ganache.py", line 133, in sleep
    return _request("evm_increaseTime", [seconds])
  File "C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\ganache.py", line 128, in _request
    raise RPCRequestError("Web3 is not connected.")
brownie.exceptions.RPCRequestError: Web3 is not connected.
```

I tried addressing this by launching my ganache UI before running the test. However, when doing so my test fails, with a VirtualMachineError.

**The full readout:**

```
PS D:\Remix Projects\Patrick Colins\Solidity with Python\Lesson7 - Lottery> brownie test --network mainnet-fork
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

====================================================================================================== test session starts ======================================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: D:\Remix Projects\Patrick Colins\Solidity with Python\Lesson7 - Lottery
plugins: eth-brownie-1.18.1, hypothesis-6.27.3, forked-1.4.0, xdist-1.34.0, web3-5.27.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Attached to local RPC client listening at '127.0.0.1:8545'...

tests\test_lottery.py F                                                                                                                                                                                                    [100%]

=========================================================================================================== FAILURES ============================================================================================================ 
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_entranceFee ________________________________________________________________________________________________________ 

    def test_entranceFee():
        account = accounts[0]
        lottery = Lottery.deploy(config["networks"][network.show_active()]["ethusd_pricefeed"],{"from": account})

>       print(lottery.getEntranceFee())

tests\test_lottery.py:10:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py:1710: in __call__
    return self.transact(*args)
C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py:1583: in transact
    return tx["from"].transfer(
C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py:682: in transfer
    receipt._raise_if_reverted(exc)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <Transaction '0x724f5c0d843d7d7932130c7c7a4ae1a61a9bbad4aeef7726fa47dd579a319d4c'>
exc = VirtualMachineError(ValueError({'message': 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert', 'code': -32000, 'data'...double.js:627:24)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)', 'name': 'RuntimeError'}}))

    def _raise_if_reverted(self, exc: Any) -> None:
        if self.status or CONFIG.mode == "console":
            return
        if not web3.supports_traces:
            # if traces are not available, do not attempt to determine the revert reason
            raise exc or ValueError("Execution reverted")

        if self._dev_revert_msg is None:
            # no revert message and unable to check dev string - have to get trace
            self._expand_trace()
        if self.contract_address:
            source = ""
        elif CONFIG.argv["revert"]:
            source = self._traceback_string()
        else:
            source = self._error_string(1)
            contract = state._find_contract(self.receiver)
            if contract:
                marker = "//" if contract._build["language"] == "Solidity" else "#"
                line = self._traceback_string().split("\n")[-1]
                if marker + " dev: " in line:
                    self._dev_revert_msg = line[line.index(marker) + len(marker) : -5].strip()

>       raise exc._with_attr(
            source=source, revert_msg=self._revert_msg, dev_revert_msg=self._dev_revert_msg
        )
E       brownie.exceptions.VirtualMachineError: revert
E       Trace step -1, program counter 310:
E         File "contracts/Lottery.sol", line 28, in Lottery.getEntranceFee:    
E           //calc entrance fee in eth
E           function getEntranceFee() public returns(uint) {
E               //get eth/usd
E               (,int price,,,) = ethusd_pricefeed.latestRoundData();
E               uint eth_usd = (uint(price) * 10**10);  // ETH/USD rate received in 8dp, multiply by 10**10 to make 18 dp
E               // convert to eth = usd/ethPrice

C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\transaction.py:446: VirtualMachineError
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Transaction sent: 0x724f5c0d843d7d7932130c7c7a4ae1a61a9bbad4aeef7726fa47dd579a319d4c
======================================================================================================= warnings summary ======================================================================================================== 
C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py:44
  C:\Users\PC\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py:44: BrownieEnvironmentWarning: Development network has a block height of 2
    warnings.warn(

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
==================================================================================================== short test summary info ==================================================================================================== 
FAILED tests/test_lottery.py::test_entranceFee - brownie.exceptions.VirtualMachineError: revert
================================================================================================= 1 failed, 1 warning in 1.70s ==================================================================================================
```

Questions:

1. I should not be running ganache UI when deploying forks, as brownie would attach itself to the UI environment and not pull from the alchemy fork - Is this understand correct?
2. Regarding the connection reset issue - how can i rectify it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This problem likely happens because you try to access a function that has no "view" atrribute.

Wrong:

```
function PrintSomething() public returns(uint256){
  uint256 res = 256;
  return res;
}
```

Right:

```
function PrintSomething() public view returns(uint256){
  uint256 res = 256;
  return res;
}
```